# ¿Cómo se dice en español «back-channel responses»?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

La oración original es *Using more back-channel responses*. He buscado en varios diccionarios pero no encuentro ninguna respuesta.

Este es el texto completo:

> Research indicates that we can help children's narrative structure by intervening with specific strategies;
>
> 1. Asking open-ended questions
> 2. Ask context-eliciting questions
> 3. Using more back-channel responses. Use phatic comments like Yeah?, Oh!, Really? Wow!

Comment: The phrase is to short and lacks more content. Do you have the text?

Comment: Tal vez wikipedia te ayude a contextualizar un poco http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backchannel_(linguistics)

Answer (score 4):

Looking around for papers on the topic in Spanish, I've seen that the term is taken directly from English.  That said, I did find it the underlying concept translated as **canales alternos de comunicación** ([source](http://asegrabci2009.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/canales-alternos-de-comunicacinbackchannel-communication/)).

This seems to me to express the concept pretty well, but as is common when using coined terms from other languages that aren't fully adapted, you should probably mention note the term in the original and work from there.  A possible way would be:

> Yngve desarrolló la idea de *back-channel communication* (canales alternos de comunicación).  Los canales alternos constituyen un medio por que el escuchante activo puede indicar al locutor con respuestas tanto verbales como físicas que entiende o que tiene prestada la atención.  Las respuestas en este tipo de comunicación … Una formulación típica de una respuesta en el canal alterno … etcétera

You can see how a professor in Argentina used the term in English in [a pedagogical paper](http://www.unlp.edu.ar/uploads/docs/el_uso_de_herramientas_de_la_web_2_0_y__back_channel_communications__en_una_clase_de_lengua_extranjera_.pdf), but still used many terms in Spanish to refer to the distinct elements within the concept, for another example of how to work with it.

Edit:

Buscando más posibilidades, he encontrado en algunos artículos el término «turno de apoyo» (que constrasta con «turno de habla») para significar una instancia de comunicación «back-channel» (de apoyo) y de «front-channel» (de habla).  He aquí algunos: [1º](http://www.nebrija.com/revista-linguistica/files/articulosPDF/articulo_5285fa27d8676.pdf), [2º](http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/18/18_0407.pdf) y [3º](http://www.nebrija.com/revista-linguistica/files/articulosPDF/articulo_52947e01a919a.pdf) (parece que el término disfruta de un uso bastante amplio)

Comment: canales alternos de comunicación es un concepto utilizado en informatica (basado en tu fuente), no en sicología como lo indica la pregunta.

Comment: @syrux la pregunta no está hablando de psicología sino pedagogía/aprendizaje lingüístico. De todas formas, ¿sabes de dónde viene el término informático? Lo tomaron los informáticos de la jerga lingüística que sí es lo que se trata en la pregunta.

Comment: aparte de que es imposible determinar de que area es la pregunta, (debido a que el tamaño es muy corto), la palabra backchannel si tiene un significado especial en Sicología de ahí mi afirmación, además el hecho de se haya tomado de otro terreno no significa que el significado sea el mismo, en Inglés es común encontrar palabras iguales con distintos significados que se determinan según su contexto, por eso ¿por que emplear un termino informático cuando la palabra tiene un significado especial en su area?.

Comment: @syrux si hubiese buscado el origen del término, lo sabrías.  El término lingüístico «back-channel communication» habla de las señales de conversación no principales (es decir, una conversación secundaria o subyacente que tiene lugar a la misma vez).  La dicha «back-channel response» es simplemente un gesto o dicho dentro de esta conversación secundaria que mantiene la conversación secundaria que, en torno, mantiene la conversación principal.

Comment: El término informático viene de esta base — comunicaciones no principales, normalmente apoyando la continuidad de una conexión. Por ejemplo, en una transferencia de un archivo grande,  los datos del archivo constituye la conversación principal, y puede haber una segunda conexión que refleja el estado de ambos ordenadores (o sea, aceptan nuevas conexiones, si habrá más archivos después, etc) con pings para asegurar la vitalidad de la conexión.

Comment: Sabemos que debe ser de pedagogía porque habla de técnicas típicas en la enseñanza de primaria.  La idea es de sacar más de (p.ej.) «Fui al supermercado».  1 sugiere preguntas como «¿Y qué hiciste allí?», 2 como «¿Por qué decidiste ir al supermercado?».  3 es una sugerencia para cuando un niño dice «Compré una manzana», la respuesta de «¿En serio?» puede sacar una continuación como «Sí, es que la manzana es mi fruta favorita, y mi madre nos iba a preparar una tarta con ellas.  Prefiero las verdes porque son más ácidas».  Como estudié pedagogía, he visto muchos textos como este.

Comment: el significado que usted menciono es el mas frecuente pero no el unico, el backchannel en sicología (permitame recordarle que la pedagogia utiliza recursos de la sicología) significa un gesto o expresión que ayuda a la continuidad de la conversacion (incluso busque en google backchannel response define), el de canal alterno es para otros usos, Otra cosa el leído libros de sicologia relacionados a test de personalidad y comportamiento en los niños que son bastante parecidos al tema tratado en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

### Turno de habla o Mecanismo de devolución de canal.

*In most of the cases the term has not been translated, below are some rare translations.*

En [este](http://eprints.uanl.mx/1127/1/1020149208.PDF) se traduce como **turno de habla** (note el nombre del capítulo de donde se ha extraído el fragmento):

> 3.5. Las interrupciones y el **turno de habla** .................................47
>
> Para Li-chiung Yang, (...) este tipo de retroalimentación (**back
>   channel** signals) "often overlap with the main speaker's speech, but
>   they are not interruptions as they do not interrupt the main speaker's
>   flow". Por lo general estas respuestas mínimas son realizadas por un
>   hablante durante el **turno de habla** de otro hablante. Para poder
>   considerar **a las  emisiones de habla como turnos** deben de tener en
>   cuenta además de un mensaje  referencial y fáctico las intenciones del
>   hablante según los límites del mensaje.

En [este](http://www.mecd.gob.es/dctm/redele/Material-RedEle/Biblioteca/2004_BV_02/2004_BV_02_13Martin_Peris.pdf?documentId=0901e72b80e412c4) artículo se menciona diferente:

> Existen también otros **mecanismos**, denominados “**de devolución de canal**”
>   (back-channel response) para cuando un participante no quiere tomar el
>   turno, o simplemente quiere indicar que está prestando atención al
>   mensaje.

En [este](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=179555) foro también se habla sobre otro artículo diferente que menciona las palabras anteriores:

> En este documento he encontrado la traducción de esa expresión como
>   "**mecanismos de devolución de canal**." (¿Eh?) Explican el gesto como una
>   forma más o menos inconsciente de apoyar a otros por medio de
>   comunicación casi no verbal.

Comment: Normalmente cuando veo usado el término *retroalimentación* en trabajos lingüísticos/pedagógicos, es más para el término inglés *feedback* (por alguna razón rarísima, a pesar de la existencia del término español, suélese usar casi universalmente la jerga inglesa) que es un término que engloba varios conceptos, del cual el *back-channel* constaría uno

Comment: @guifa, mi respuesta lo que trata es de aclarar la oración, no espero una equivalencia entre ambos lenguajes, puesto que no veo una traducción práctica para backchannel response. Vi la fuente que mencionaste pero las palabras que usan ellos es backchannel communication, no backchannel response como se pide en la pregunta.

Comment: Creo que el autor del documento en tu actualización ha malentendido la palabra *back-channel* como «canal por el que se devuelven cosas» (que sería *return-channel* en inglés), cuando significa «canal subyacente, de fondo, o que no es principal».  Ese malentendido y su traducción consecuente explicaría el «¿Eh?» del foro, que para mí no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: @guifa, para mí tampoco tiene sentido pero dos documentos mencionan el mismo conjunto de palabras (por sicólogos profesionales) (el foro lleva a otro documento) a pesar de eso encontre otra traducción diferente.

Comment: @guifa, en mi respuesta anterior explique detalladamente que el back-channel response, es en efecto parte de un intercambio, y si no existe devolucion de frases faticas por parte del receptor la comunicacion se dificulta

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he visto en redes (topologías en estrella) como **canal de retorno**. No se si en el entorno de la pregunta sería utilizable.